# How to run the legacy Mongo Casbah drivers alongside the modern Mongo scala drivers

Tags: mongodb, scala, sbt

The old official Scala Driver, ["casbah"](https://mongodb.github.io/casbah/), is end-of-life. There is [a new official mongo driver here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/) but the two drivers can't coexist in the same project due to the way sbt resolves conflicting library versions. They both seem to import separate major versions of an underlying `mongo-java-driver`.

I have hundreds of hand written Mongo queries that need tweaking for the new driver so having two drivers in use concurrently whilst I migrate the app query by query would be the safest and most agile approach for me, that I'd like to pursue.

I have a [sample project available here](https://github.com/PhillipTaylor/mongo-migrate-example). There are two connect functions. A new one and an old one. If you comment out the new/old pieces you will see each independently work, connect to a database and list the names of the collections.

When you include both drivers together you get this error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List 

com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getCredentialList()'
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getCredentialList()'
[error]         at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.getCredentials(MongoClientURI.java:243)
[error]         at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:637)
[error]         at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:289)
[error]         at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:268)
[error]         at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient$.apply(MongoClient.scala:201)
[error]         at example.LegacyMongoScala$.connect(Hello.scala:59)
[error]         at example.Hello$.delayedEndpoint$example$Hello$1(Hello.scala:14)
[error]         at example.Hello$delayedInit$body.apply(Hello.scala:7)
[error]         at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]         at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]         at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]         at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
[error]         at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
[error]         at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
[error]         at example.Hello$.main(Hello.scala:7)
[error]         at example.Hello.main(Hello.scala)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

I suspect the problem here is how the latest mongo-java-driver pushes out the former?

```
HOST [15:18: (main) mongo-migrate-example$] sbt dependencyTree
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.4 (Debian Java 11.0.9.1)
[info] loading settings for project global-plugins from idea.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading global plugins from /home/phill/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /home/phill/tmp/mongo-migrate-example/project
[success] Generated .bloop/mongo-migrate-example-build.json
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/phill/tmp/mongo-migrate-example/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed 5 Jan 2021, 15:19:43
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to mongo-migrate-example (in build file:/home/phill/tmp/mongo-migrate-example/)
[info] Updating 
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4.pom
  100.0% [##########] 29.4 KiB (101.2 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.pom
  100.0% [##########] 10.4 KiB (35.7 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[info] Fetching artifacts of 
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar
  100.0% [##########] 37.6 KiB (536.6 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4.jar
  100.0% [##########] 614.8 KiB (2.2 MiB / s)
[info] Fetched artifacts of 
[info] com.example:mongo-migrate-example_2.12:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info]   +-com.github.salat:salat-core_2.12:1.11.2 [S]
[info]   | +-com.github.salat:salat-util_2.12:1.11.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.json4s:json4s-native_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.8
[info]   | | |   +-org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.5 (evicted by: 1.0.6)
[info]   | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6 [S]
[info]   | | |   
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang:scalap:2.12.12
[info]   | | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.12 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.12 [S]
[info]   | | |   
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.json4s:json4s-native_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.8
[info]   | |   +-org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.5 (evicted by: 1.0.6)
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6 [S]
[info]   | |   
[info]   | +-org.mongodb:casbah-core_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   |   | +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.14.0 [S]
[info]   |   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
[info]   |   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   |   | | 
[info]   |   | +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2
[info]   |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
[info]   |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   |   | 
[info]   |   +-org.mongodb:casbah-query_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   |     +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   |       +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.14.0 [S]
[info]   |       | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
[info]   |       | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   |       | 
[info]   |       +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2
[info]   |       +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
[info]   |       +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   |       
[info]   +-com.github.salat:salat-util_2.12:1.11.2 [S]
[info]   | +-org.json4s:json4s-native_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.8
[info]   | |   +-org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:3.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.5 (evicted by: 1.0.6)
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6 [S]
[info]   | |   
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scalap:2.12.12
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.12 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.12 [S]
[info]   | |   
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   | 
[info]   +-io.netty:netty-all:4.1.51.Final
[info]   +-org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-driver_2.12:4.1.0 [S]
[info]   | +-org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-bson_2.12:4.1.0 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.mongodb:bson:4.1.0
[info]   | | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.12 [S]
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:4.1.0
[info]   | | +-org.mongodb:bson:4.1.0
[info]   | | +-org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.1.0
[info]   | | | +-org.mongodb:bson:4.1.0
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.12 [S]
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.mongodb:casbah-core_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   | +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   | | +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.14.0 [S]
[info]   | | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
[info]   | | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   | | | 
[info]   | | +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.mongodb:casbah-query_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]   |     +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.14.0 [S]
[info]   |     | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
[info]   |     | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]   |     | 
[info]   |     +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2
[info]   |     +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
[info]   |     +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]   |     
[info]   +-org.mongodb:casbah-gridfs_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]     +-org.mongodb:casbah-core_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]       +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]       | +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.14.0 [S]
[info]       | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
[info]       | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]       | | 
[info]       | +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2
[info]       | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
[info]       | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]       | 
[info]       +-org.mongodb:casbah-query_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]         +-org.mongodb:casbah-commons_2.12:3.1.1 [S]
[info]           +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.14.0 [S]
[info]           | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
[info]           | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]           | 
[info]           +-org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2
[info]           +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
[info]           +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
[info]           
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 5 Jan 2021, 15:19:45
```

Question 1: Can someone suggest an approach which might work?

I have tried creating a library (using sbt new, then adding a single dependency + sbt-assembly plugin) which only expose a `connect` function and then used `sbt-assembly` plugin to shade the dependencies. Using this technique I can rename `com.mongodb` to `shadedlegacy.mongodb` and see this inside the assembled jar when I open it with a zip tool. I can used the renamed symbols in my applications but internally there are still errors thrown about subsequent classes and I'm not sure if this is just a rabbit hole with no end, all caused by the fact `mongo-java-driver` is shared by both and always evicted:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Error running public static void app.Boot.main(java.lang.String[]).
[error] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class org.bson.BSON from class com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.OptionSerializer (org.bson.BSON and com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.OptionSerializer are in unnamed module of loader sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader @2d8d2575)
[error] If using a layered classloader, this can occur if jvm package private classes are accessed across layers. This can be fixed by changing to the Flat or ScalaInstance class loader layering strategies.
[error] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Error running public static void app.Boot.main(java.lang.String[]).
[error] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class org.bson.BSON from class com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.OptionSerializer (org.bson.BSON and com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.OptionSerializer are in unnamed module of loader sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader @2d8d2575)
[error] If using a layered classloader, this can occur if jvm package private classes are accessed across layers. This can be fixed by changing to the Flat or ScalaInstance class loader layering strategies.
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
```

Question 3: Is this approach above of shading both libraries one that could work?

Question 4: Would [this sbt-shading library](https://github.com/coursier/sbt-shading/#sbt-shading) offer any alternative solutions that couldn't be reach via sbt-assembly?

Question 5: Is there any approaches using custom classloaders that could potentially lead me to success?

Question 6: If you've moved between drivers was it ever easier at some point? Am I over-estimating the complexity? I can't find any upgrade guides.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is question 2?

Comment: You seem to be using a layered class loader. Have you tried using a flat classloader strategy instead? See the docs on how to do that: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.3-Release-Notes.html

Comment: You could also try migrating to an older mongo-scala-driver who's dependencies are compatible with casbah's. Then once you got rid of casbah, upgrade to a more recent mongo-scala-driver.

Comment: @Philluminati what did you do in the end? Did you manage to run both?

Comment: @StefanStojkovski Sad news my brother, we still run Scala 2.12 because of this casbah dependency. I [tried patching casbah to run on Scala 2.13, didnt fully test it](https://github.com/PhillipTaylor/casbah213) but the salat dependency relies on scala internal reflection apis which are straight un-portable.

Comment: @Philluminati we did manage to run both in parallel using an older version of the mongo-scala-driver which is 2.9.0 and also explicitly upping the mongo-java-driver to 3.12.2 which evicts version 3.2.2 which is a dependency for casbah. This means that source compatibility for the java driver might be broken but we haven't' had any issues with casbah for now. We run both on dev environment in parallel without problems and our plan is to ditch casbah before releasing to prod, and also to upgrade mongo-scala-driver from 2.9.0 to latest, hopefully with only minor refactor.